# Computing Resultant Point And Magnitude Of Rotation

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotation

[image: ![enter image description here]

Say that I have a free body quad rotor aircraft with torque induced rotation at points A, B, C and D with angular velocities $\omega_a$, $\omega_b$, $\omega_c$ and $\omega_d$ respectively.

I have always thought that the resultant rotation axis C and magnitude $\omega_c$ between two points say P and Q with angular velocities $\omega_p$ and $\omega_q$ respectively is

$$ P = \left(P_x,P_y\right)$$
$$ Q = \left(Q_x,Q_y\right)$$
$$k=\frac{\|\omega_q\|}{\|\omega_p\|+\|\omega_q\|}$$
$$L=\sqrt{\left(Q_y-P_y\right)^2+\left(Q_x-P_x\right)^2}$$
$$D=kL$$
$$C_x=P_x+\frac{D\left(Q_x-P_x\right)}{L}$$
$$C_y=P_y+\frac{D\left(Q_y-P_y\right)}{L}$$
$$ C = \left(C_x,C_y\right)$$
$$\omega_c = \omega_p + \omega_q$$

This is due to a realization that in $\theta = \delta\omega$ in
$$
k = \cos\theta_p-\frac{\sin\theta_p\left(\cos\theta_p+\cos\theta_q-1\right)}{\sin\theta_p+\sin\theta_q}
$$

can be made very small that small a`enter preformatted text here`ngle approximation can be used and the linear part coincides with $k=\frac{\|\omega_q\|}{\|\omega_p\|+\|\omega_q\|}$

See [Small angle coincidence](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dnumiraa7a)
See [Other k derivation and visualization](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xgxdk3sgod)
But boy I've never been so wrong.

```
import math
# calculate resultant rotation point and magnitude
# paramerters: a, b
# where a and b is a tuple of (x,y,angle_speed)
def combine(a,b):
    Px, Py, Pt = a
    Qx, Qy, Qt = b
    aPt = abs(Qt)
    aQt = abs(Pt)
    k = 1.*aPt/(aPt+aQt)
    L = math.sqrt((Qy-Py)**2+(Qx-Px)**2)
    D = k*L
    t = Pt + Qt
    return (
        Px + D*(Qx-Px)/L ,
        Py + D*(Qy-Py)/L ,
        t)
a = ( 0, 5, 5)
b = ( 5, 0,-3)
c = ( 0,-5, 4)
d = (-5, 0,-6)
ab = combine(a,b)
cd = combine(c,d)
abcd = combine(ab,cd)
ac = combine(a,c)
bd = combine(b,d)
acbd = combine(ac,bd)
print abcd
print acbd
```

According to this operation isn't even commutative. :'(
**EOTTEOKE HELP**

How do I compute it properly?